# premature closings

Tags: discussion, closing

I have noticed a number of attempts to *close* questions within hours if not minutes of their having been asked. This seems premature to me. I tried to search this meta site for "premature closings" without any result.

*Are there guidelines as to how long the OP should get the benefit of the doubt before we throw the book at her?*

If a question is offensive speedy closing (and deletion) are of course appropriate, similarly in the case of a duplicate, but I have noticed many cases of questions that don't fall into these categories.

It was mentioned in one of the comments that an other problematic group of questions is "suspected homework". This could also benefit from more explicit guidelines.

A recent example is discussed below in the comments. Another recent example: Tracy [tried once](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889204/is-there-an-odd-integer-other-than-1-that-is-the-sum-of-its-divisors), was in my opinion prematurely closed, but [showed some determination and didn't give up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889916/is-there-an-odd-integer-other-than-1-that-is-the-sum-of-its-divisors), and got 2 useful answers. What *should* have happened?

Note: a relevant link http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13016/too-quick-to-close

Comment: It depends on the author, the question, and the [mood of the] people voting to close.

Comment: Moody closings is precisely the problem.

Comment: Well, when we evolve into being robots, ten million years from now, this won't be a problem. So in any case it is a temporary issue. (Read: humans are moody creatures, not much to do about that.)

Comment: If someone comes here and states a question, and this question is from their assessed homework, and someone answers this question before the question is closed then the closure was pointless. So quick closures are not a bad thing per se. Also, I should point out that questions are not "closed" immediately, but rather are put "on hold". They can be "released" by improving them, and *theoretically* the releasing time should be no longer than the time it took for the question to be put on-hold. (Of course, theory is often different from practice...)

Comment: You're right in that it is a problem. It is largely to prevent *premature answers*, but the way it is done is not always to my taste either. The point is that there is no way to agree on criteria that we would all accept (and commit to following). It is an evolution of sorts, and therefore has random fluctuations. This chaos is way better than having a dictator make those decisions for us. Nobody here agrees with the closings 100% of the time. As a 10k user you can throw your weight around yourself, and vote to reopen, if you don't like what you see happening.

Comment: @Jyrki, thanks for your comment. This issue does not seem to be controversial to an extent that some mild guidelines allowing the OP some breathing space should be entirely out of the question!

Comment: The point of putting a question on hold *is precisely* to give "breathing space" for improving a question in need of improving. It can be quite unfortunate if (non-)answers are given based on an incomplete or faulty understanding of a question. Your objection seems based on a misunderstanding of the putting on hold/closing process.

Comment: @quid, I refer you to this recent case where the question was clear enough but trigger-happy closers were at work minutes after the question was posed: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889867/limit-question-lim-x-rightarrow-a-frac3x-what-does-the-a-represen   There should be away of introducing mild guidelines to limit the trigger happy behavior.

Comment: To describe the question as "clear enough" in its *original* form seems like an overstatement. To link to the current form is somewhat disingenious in my opinion; here is the link to the original form http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/889867/1 And notice that some user that eventually answered, at first did not understand the question. Thus some knowledgable person making a good faith effort to understand the question could not. So it was not "clear enough." But I agree at the moment there is no reason to put it on hold.

Comment: @quid I am glad we agree. The difference between the two forms is purely typographic though.

Comment: If one looks at it correctly then, yes. But one can also read it differently, as spelled out in a comment. Reading the "a"  not as a variable but a spurious word.

Comment: @quid, aah, I see the problem, didn't realize this before.

Comment: @user I was the first person to vote to close, but I have retracted my vote with the edit. I commented on the post at the time - my issue, as quid has pointed out, was the odd "a". Although I think I didn't make this clear in my comment...

Comment: @quid Please do explain how you can *sensibly* 
"read it differently". I see no sensible way to do so.

Comment: @BillDubuque in order to honor your request it needs to be clarified what 'can *sensibly* "read it differently"'means precisely. There are at least two readings of it (your request). To avoid confusion and a back-and-forth, I will adress both: I do not see any other reading that directly leads to a question that makes sense. Possibly, this is what you meant, however this is not what I meant and the only thing that is relevant. Namely, to me a sensible reading is an interpretation that a sensible and knowledgeable person could make (whether the outcome makes sense or not is orthogonal, [cont..]

Comment: as it is not the case that one can assume on this site that each question written makes sense).  *Visibly* more than one user that seem very sensible and knowledgeable (not me by the way, I had not seen the question before the meta when it was already clarfified) had difficulty to understand the intended meaning. Thus, clearly there are other sensible ways to interpret the text. If you insist I can spell our such interpretations, however, since your comment might be based on erroneus (though perhaps still sensible) interpretation  of my earlier comment, I will not do so right away. ( @Bill )

Comment: @quid I'm glad you agree that there is a unique sensible way to parse the question. I'm not at all surprised that a couple users might complain about the lack of formatting.

Comment: @BillDubuque as said the first part of the comment is true if we adopt your usage of parsing in a sensible way, which I consider not to be the only or even mainly relevant one in this context. I take it the second part is also true, and only add that this is not (all) what happened.

Comment: Let's not focus too much on a specific case. It is clear that when a post is a duplicate of an earlier one, it is appropriate to react immediately. I was hoping one of the mediators would propose a mild wording discourading trigger-happy closings/holdings.

Comment: Your wording is problematic in my opinion. For example "trigger-happy" and "through the book" suggest agression and this feels unwarranted. I would also have a slight preferrence not to be mentioned in OP in this form, it makes it look a bit as if I had to do anything with that attempted closures.

Comment: For your second pair of examples **again** link to the version that got closed http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/889204/1 It is a *quite* different question as it asks about *negative* numbers where it is quite unclear what sum of divisors means (or at least which meaning should be used, any one I can think of makes the question pointless, as also detailed in comments). The edit and the second question are completely different questions, that should have been asked right away as a new q without edit. Further OP got an answer to the question they then reask in the  comments on the first.

Comment: The closing was not only completely justfied but actually helpful. In this way OP was presumably more motivated to ask a new question, which is what they should have done right away. As the second question is a different question than the first, not a minor modification, expansion, clarification of it. The only thing that went wrong (community moderation wise) was that the edit got approved.

Comment: @quid, when I looked at the question I had the impression that the "negative" was deleted quite soon, and did not result in a re-opening. Otherwise why would the OP start another thread?

Comment: @quid as far as "trigger-happy" I am not enabled to edit *comments* but feel free replace them all by "premature".

Comment: What does your first comment mean? That you maintain this or that you acknowledge an error. Either way: The question was closed 20 hours ago. The edit was proposed 4 hours ago. *A few minutes* before the new post. The edit took even effect only after the new post. I do not know why OP did what they did. Most likely as they are still confused about the workings of the site. Anyway the current status is about as it should be. To make it perfect one should rollback the edit, but perhaps it is not worth it.

Comment: Even "premature" makes a judgement. If I write OP how I think it should be written it would be completely different.

Comment: @quid: I agree that the edit should be rolled back. In fact, it shouldn't have been approved. Anonymous edits changing the meaning of the question completely are bad.

Comment: @quid, some of the responders understood right away what the meaning of the question was and commented that it is an open problem. The OP should have been given the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: More specifically, @AdamHughes responded within minutes *to the first question* with an "open problem" comment... And then voted to close it!

Comment: The second question is most certainly not the meaning of the first question. How in the world should  the negative have appeared. Indeed Adam Hughes comments the question makes no sense and **voted to close**. The first question makes no sense. The comments possibly gave OP the idea to ask a completely different question.

Comment: @Asaf I rolled back now and left a comment. This also fixes in some way the issue with the missleading link in OP.

Comment: "I tried to search this meta site for *premature closings* without any result." Have a look at the questions listed under Related on this page, e.g., my question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13016/too-quick-to-close

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks, that's helpful. My position is not that specific guidelines should be adopted, but that *there should be some guidelines*.

Answer (score 11):

As quid said,

> Your objection seems based on a misunderstanding of the putting on hold/closing process.

I would suggest reading [The War of the Closes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) for an explanation of how the $$\text{[on hold]}\to \begin{cases}\text{[reopen]} \\ \text{[closed]} \end{cases}$$

works. In a nutshell: users are given **five days** to improve the question, and during this period the system facilitates the reopening.

Also, the rhetoric of "throwing the book at someone" is misplaced. Closing is applied to questions, not to users. It is not an equivalent of putting OP in jail, or other sanctions. It's about   protecting the content of the site from being diluted with low-quality infusions.  It is a levée separating the site from the Great Internet Swamp. Without closing, or *with toothless, delayed closing*, the site will be [Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index?sid=396545161&link=list).

[image: yahoo]

Those who consider closing harmful are very welcome to post insightful answers and pedagogical gems  on the aforementioned site.

Comment: I fully agree that there are some cases when immediate closure is appropriate, and mentioned some of these cases in my question, but yours is a bit of a strawman criticism. There should be a way of throwing away the bathwater but keeping any babys that may be found.